# How can I force an application that needs access to my Gmail account to be read-only?

Tags: gmail

I want to make sure that an application just read my Gmail account, but does not modified anything.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You cannot make sure that an application just read my Gmail account, but does not modified anything.